# 2列 50行のテーブルを簡単に作成したいです

Tags: javascript, html, css

現在は下記のようにひとつひとつ行を作っています。

```
<table id="sampleTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>都道府県名</th>
            <th>読み</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>東京都</td>
            <td>とうきょうと</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>大阪府</td>
            <td>おおさかふ</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

しかし、50行のテーブルとなるとソース量が多くなってしまうので、
もっと簡単な記述方法があればご教授をお願いしたいです。
因みに、javaScriptを使用しても大丈夫です。

Comment: JavaScriptを実行して生成してもよいですが、要件に「JavaScriptがOFFでも動作したい」というのがあれば、自力で書くしかないですよね

Comment: javaScriptを実行して生成して大丈夫です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQueryを利用した方法は以下になります。

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    var data = [
      {name:'東京都', yomi:'とうきょうと'},
      {name:'大阪府', yomi:'おおさかふ'},
      {name:'北海道', yomi:'ほっかいどう'}
      // ...略（最後の要素にはカンマを付けないように）
    ];

    data.forEach(function(v){
      html = '<tr><td>'+v.name+'</td><td>'+v.yomi+'</td></tr>';
      $('#sampleTable tbody').append(html);
    });
  });
</script>

<table id="sampleTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>都道府県名</th>
      <th>読み</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

MVCとかMVVMとかのフレームワークライブラリを使う手もあります。
簡単な内容ならjQueryとかで書いてしまう方が楽ですが、HTMLが複雑になったときには便利です。

下記は[Knockout.js](http://kojs.sukobuto.com/docs/introduction)を使った例です。

```html
<table id="sampleTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>都道府県名</th>
            <th>読み</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: yomi"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script>
var viewmodel = {
    data: [
        { name:'東京都', yomi:'とうきょうと' },
        { name:'大阪府', yomi:'おおさかふ' }
    ]
};
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

元のデータ形式がcsv等であればcsvからhtmlを作成するサービスがありますよ。
http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-html.htm